# reversing wallet to wallet transactions(both wallets mine)

Tags: electrum

I sent BTC from my coinb.in wallet to an electrum wallet on a tails drive, but I didn't realize it was the tails iso disk, and while waiting for confirmations, I noticed id' used the tails iso disk after the transfer but before I could get confirms and send BTC back to the coinb.in wallet, Tails froze. 
So I had to reboot and that meant the tails iso disk went back to default, and the electrum wallet disappeared, so the BTC are stuck in blockchain because there weren't any confirms. 
There's got to be a way to reverse so the coins go back to my coinb.in wallet. Both wallets are mine, so, it would seem like the transfer could be returned/reversed as there's no merchant and its not a refund. Thanks

Comment: bitcoin transactions can NOT be reversed.  If you have broadcast them and they have confirmations then you will need to get them out of the wallet you transferred them to.  If the transaction has 0 confirmations and is not being accepted on the network then you can do a -rescan of your wallet to get any old balances like this back.  Hope this helps.

Comment: If this question is still open, please add the relevant information from the comments to your question post. :)

Answer (score 1):

The "owner" of a wallet is defined by whomever controls the private keys in that wallet.  If you have lost control of a wallet (the one on the ISO disk), then you are **not** the owner of that wallet anymore.  Nobody is.

If the transaction to the new wallet has not yet been confirmed and put into a block, you *might* have the option of replacing that transaction with one that goes back to your coinb.in wallet.  That depends on two things:

1. The transaction you want to replace has opted-in to [Replace-by-fee](https://bitcoincore.org/en/faq/optin_rbf/)
2. Your original wallet (coinb.in) allows you to use Replace-by-fee to broadcast a new transaction, replacing the original one

You can read more about it here:  https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_replacement

Comment: Thanks, yes I know the iso wallet is gone but I did make the key and have the 12 word seed, that's what I meant that it was mine, but now its gone.I'm learning the lingo.on blockchain.info, I saw the still unconfirmed transaction,a red box that said unconfirmed and a green one with the amount, is it still unconfirmed because I never clicked the broadcast button?I don't mind paying a fee(not too large).Should I open the top link first or read from the Wiki/transaction replacement link. Is there ifo I need to know in the bottom link?

Comment: If you still have the 12 word seed, then just restore the wallet somewhere else.  Don't worry about replacing the fee (if that's even possible in your scenario) unless you absolutely need the transaction to go through immediately.  If I were you, I'd simply restore the wallet and wait for the transaction to confirm.

Comment: I didn't click the broadcast box on coinb.in after sending. Does that mean it's possible to replace by fee?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea.  It is determined by how the site constructs transactions, and if they even have a ui for rbf.  You'd have to ask someone from the site.

Comment: to jestin. do you know that the same electrum wallet can be restored? I thought everything on tails iso gets erased. And both the tails iso and tails disks are now not working. No I don't absolutely need the transaction to go through. I just wanted the electrum wallet to be my main wallet because I wanted to use the Debian OS instead of Vista witch I'm on now beleive it or not.

Comment: @T.Mckenna'sghost, your 12-word seed can be used to recreate the wallet in its entirety...including transactions that haven't been confirmed yet.  This is the point of using an HD wallet with a 12-word seed.  So long as you have the seed, it doesn't matter what gets deleted.  You can always recreate it.  You can read the BIP for HD wallets here:  https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki

Comment: I read the links and I would need to find a step by step on how to replace by fee,unless it's simple enough for someone to explain it but I didn't get much from the links so I'm gonna google how to do that Rbf.Also When I download electrum wallet to windows,when I try to open the wallet it always says ,failed to open because side by side config.is incorrect see app. event log. Don't know what that means.

Comment: You are trying to troubleshoot too many issues at once.  First, forget rbf, since it sounds like you don't need it.  Just focus on restoring the wallet.  If electrum won't run, figure that out next.  If it tells you to check a log...then check the log.  Nobody can help you if you don't.  Once it's running, restore your wallet from seed.

Comment: Okay, I got an Electrum wallet to install (with errors). Could some body please help me out with what to do next,just send the funds back to my coinb.in wallet? Oh then click broadcast? any help is invaluable,and thanks to Jestin for help earlier.

Comment: To Jestin, I finally got an electrum wallet to install. And I followed your instruction to find my wallet,but it's got errors. It won't let me send the BTC to a wallet address I paste in the box, it has a different address when I preveiw it .

Comment: To Jestin, or anyone who read the whole question and thinks they can help. I finally got an electrum wallet to install. And I followed your instruction to find my wallet,but it's got errors. It won't let me send the BTC to a wallet address I paste in the box, it has a different address when I preview it . On blockchain and at first in the wallet, the amount was exact 0.09512741 (0.09512), then the amount in electrum  went up to 95+ BTC! Blockchain still has correct amount and address/other info.

Comment: I would move this to chat but I don't have reps.

Comment: At this point you should ask a new question, since you are troubleshooting something else.  It makes it easier for other people to find the answer.  Always remember that the point of this site is to create a knowledge base, not to troubleshoot individual issues.

Comment: Thank you for help, but should I stop adding comments here and just email

Comment: Any thoughts on how to force a wallet address of my choosing into the address bar in the send tab on these unstable electrum wallets I have to create . I don't know the address that's there, but it's not mine  and it doesn't erase and I can't paste over it, it's stuck. I need to buy some things with my BTC and can't from this/these wallets. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about either Electrum nor coinb.in.  You would get more eyes on your follow up questions if you posted them as new questions.

Comment: LAST COMMENT FROM ME HERE  I would ask new questions, but people it seems who notice the new question asked , then start asking "why not just buy stuff from the wallet your BTC are in as they don't know the whole situation. Not saying I won't ask some new questions, They just won't know some details,and I'd feel like explaining everything. Thanks Jestin and all who've helped.

Comment: In the future please don't use comments for discussions but rather amend your respective posts to provide the additionally requested information. Also, I think that the required reputation is waved when a comment discussion gets moved to chat, otherwise please ping a moderator, so we can invite you to the chat manually.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear which transaction confirmed happened, so I'll answer both possible scenarios:

1. If both transactions did not confirm, you should attempt to have your coinb.in wallet forget about the transactions, and send your coins from the coinb.in wallet to a new address on the coinb.in wallet, so that the old transactions become invalidated and don't confirm at a later time.
2. If the first transaction confirmed, but the second did not, you should either

   - restore your Electrum wallet somewhere else and create a new transaction to send the money where you want it.
   - create a child-pays-for-parent transaction, i.e. create a transaction in coinb.in that spends the unconfirmed transaction output you are trying to receive from the Electrum wallet. You'd need to add a larger fee as it needs to pay enough to make it worthwhile to include both transactions in a block.

Hopefully, this was resolved already, but perhaps someone else will be able to use the information. :)